# VB 2010 Express Webrowser Scrollto

Tags: vb.net, scrollbar, webbrowser-control

I load a pdf document into a Webrowser:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("F:/Documents/headache.pdf")
```

Using a button I want to scroll to a position someway down the browser:

```
Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, 50)
```

On running the code I get the error "NullReferenceException was unhandled". I have searched high and low for a solution but everything I find says my code should work (ie worked for others). Hope some one can help me.

---

So. After a little more research and head scratching, the WebBrowser1.Navigate will not set the WebBrowser1.Document to a PDF. (Of course the code works no problem with HTML.)

MY **SOULTION**: I replaced the Webrowser with an AxAcroPDF1 Control and used

```
Me.AxAcroPDF1.setViewScroll("FitH", 50)
```

to scroll through the document.

Comment: Make sure `Document` is not nothing first. For example: `If Me.WebBrowser1.Document IsNot Nothing Then...`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but then the ScrollTo is bypassed completely. In the watch window Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Window is 'always' Nothing. I'm guessing it is maybe because I loaded a PDF? (and not a HTML based page). I'm guessing.